# Can't find kpsewhich in Miktex distribution

Tags: latex

When I try to run kpsewhich from the terminal I get the command not found error even though running tex works. I believe Miktex didn't install kpsewhich on my mac because I can't find a file with that name (or kpathseaemulator, etc...). Can somebody help me to install it? I am running MikTex 2.9.6600 on MacOs High Sierra.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: No. I ended up switching Tex distributions. I am now using MacTex, which I’ve found better suited for Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/294) in the Miktex installation. The symlink to the executable is not created.

The workaround is to create the link manually, until the problem is fixed.

```
ln -s '/Applications/MiKTeX Console.app/Contents/bin/miktex-kpsewhich' kpsewhich
```